# Why doesn't answerInlineQuery method of telegram bot work?

Tags: php, telegram, telegram-bot

I have a telegram bot that works in inline mode - when I type his username, then the person's username and text, the bot should pop up an inline window to send a message in the group to that person.

Until some point, my bot worked without problems, but then it began to return empty responses to inline requests:
[image]

I thought that telegram updated this method and began to look for differences. And yes, I noticed that the link fields and image sizes changed from thumb_url to thumbnail_url.

I changed them, but the error did not disappear, even if I comment out the lines with adding an image to the inline button.

The database also records all messages and other necessary data.

But now I have no ideas, because of what my inline in the telegram bot broke, here is my code for inline requests:

```
`$language = get_language_for_inline_query($inline_user_id); // Get the language selected by the user (For inline mod)

// Get last id from DB and add 1 to insert into callback_data (How message_id is used)
$callback_message_id = get_id();
$callback_id = ($callback_message_id['id'] + 1);

if (isset($inline_query)) {
    $answer_inline_query = [
        "inline_query_id" => $inline_query_id,
        "results" => '',
    ];

    $inline_receiver_explode = explode(" ", $inline_query_msg); // Separate the tagged user from the post
    $inline_receiver_username = $inline_receiver_explode[0];
    $delete = ltrim($inline_receiver_username, '@'); // Removing the dog in front of the username/ID
    $clear_query = ltrim(str_replace($inline_receiver_username, '', $inline_query_msg)); // Removing the username/id from the message

    // If the request has a username through @ from 5 characters and text, then display a pop-up window with sending a message
    if (preg_match('/^@[\w]{5,32}\s.{1,200}$/', $inline_query_msg)) {

        $response = sendRequest('answerInlineQuery?inline_query_id=' . $inline_query_id . '&cache_time=' . 1 . '&results=' . json_encode(
                [
                    [
                        "type" => "article",
                        "id" => "2",
                        "title" => set_language($language, 'send_title'),
                        "description" => set_language($language, 'send_description'),
                        $secret_button = [[['text' => set_language($language, 'send_button'), 'callback_data' => $inline_username . '-' . $callback_id]]],
                        "reply_markup" => json_decode(inline_keyboard($secret_button)),
                        "input_message_content" => [
                            "message_text" => set_language($language, 'send_text_1') . $inline_receiver_username . set_language($language, 'send_text_2')
                        ]
                        "thumbnail_url" => "s1.yli.ink/jocbvu.jpg",
                        "thumbnail_width" => "512",
                        "thumbnail_height" => "512"
                    ]
                ]
            )
        );

        // Register a new request (secret message)
        message_reg($inline_username, $inline_user_id, $clear_query, $delete, $inline_first_name);
    }
    $response = sendRequest('answerInlineQuery?inline_query_id=' . $inline_query_id . '&cache_time=' . 1 . '&results=' . json_encode(
            [
                [
                    "type" => "article",
                    "id" => "1",
                    "title" => set_language($language, 'help_title'),
                    "description" => set_language($language, 'help_description'),
                    "input_message_content" => [
                        "message_text" => set_language($language, 'help_text'),
                        "parse_mode" => "html"
                    ]
                    "thumbnail_url" => "s1.yli.ink/lopqge.jpg",
                    "thumbnail_width" => "512",
                    "thumbnail_height" => "512"
                ]
            ]
        )
    );
}
`
```